# Borel measure - unbounded sets

Tags: general-topology, borel-measures

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ be borel-measurable and $\mu (E) < + \infty $, I have to show the following:
$$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} \mu ((E + \{ x \}) \cap E)=0  $$
A hint suggests to first consider bounded sets $E$.
My proof for bounded sets would be:
$E$ bounded $\Rightarrow \exists L \in \mathbb{R} $, s.t. $\forall a \in E: |a|< L \Rightarrow \forall x > 2L: x > $ sup$(E) - $ inf$(E)$ 
$ \Rightarrow $ inf$(E) + x > $ sup $ (E) \Rightarrow \forall x > 2L: \mu ((E + \{ x \}) \cap E)= \mu( \emptyset )= 0$ 
$ \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to +\infty} \mu ((E + \{ x \}) \cap E)=0  $

However, I do not really have an idea how to use that to show it for $E$ unbounded, because $E$ unbounded and $\mu (E) < + \infty$ seems counterintuative to me.

Comment: For the "counterintuitive" item at the end of your question, consider $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty[n,n+2^{-n}]$. For the question itself, show first that, given any $E$ as in the question and any $\epsilon>0$, you can decompose $E$ into a bounded Borel set and a set of measure $<\epsilon$.